# How to implement a vertically and horizontally HTML table with multiple fixed columns?

Tags: html, css

I have created a table with multiple column headers with titles and multiple rows with multiples fixed or frozen cells at the beginning of each row.

My current result (see [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/schlebe/84xLk1ns/5/)) work well for vertical scrolling but don't work for horizontal scrolling.

Here is my full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SOLAIRE table</title>

    <style>
        thead,
        tfoot
            {
            background-color: #FFFFC0;
            color: black;
            }
        
        body
            {
            min-height: 100%;
            font-family: "Arial";
            font-size: 1.4em;
            }

        td  {
            text-align: right;
            width: 4em;
            padding: 4px;
            }

        tr.middleRow td
            {
            border-top: 1px dashed black;
            border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
            border-left: 1px solide black;
            border-right: 1px solid black;
            }

        tr.topRow td
            {
            border-top: 1px solid black;
            border-left: 1px solid black;
            border-right: 1px solid black;
            }

        tr.bottomRow td
            {
            border-bottom: 1px solid black;
            border-left: 1px solid black;
            border-right: 1px solid black;
            }

        tr.erow td 
            {
            height: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            border: 0;
            padding: 2px;
            }

        thead th
            {
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            background-color: #FFFFC0;
            color: black;
            text-align: right;
            padding: 4px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            font-weight: normal;
            z-index: 24;
            }

        tbody th
            {
            position: sticky;
            z-index: 20;
            background-color: #CCFFCC;
            color: black;
            text-align: right;
            padding: 4px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            font-weight: normal;
            }

        table
            {
            border-spacing: 0;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            
        .no {
            left: 0;
            }
            
        .month
            {
            left: 20;
            }
            
        .min
            {
            left: 120;
            }
            
        .avg
            {
            left: 160;
            }
            
        .max
            {
            left: 200;
            }

    </style>
</head>
  
<body>
    <table width="100%" height="100%">
        <col style="width:20px">
        <col style="width:100px">
        <col style="width:40px">
        <col style="width:40px">
        <col style="width:40pt">
        <col style="width:40px">
        <col style="width:40px">
        <col style="width:40px">
        <col style="width:40px">
        <col style="width:40px">
        <col style="width:40px">
        <col style="width:40px">
        <col style="width:40px">
        <col style="width:40px">
        <col style="width:40px">
        <col style="width:40px">
        <col style="width:40px">
        <col style="width:40px">
        <col style="width:40px">
        <col style="width:40px">
        <col style="width:40px">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="no">#</th>
                <th class="month">Mois</th>
                <th class="min">Min</th>
                <th class="avg">Avg</th>
                <th class="max">Max</th>
                <th>2012</th><th>2013</th><th>2014</th><th>2015</th><th>2016</th><th>2017</th><th>2018</th><th>2019</th><th>2020</th><th>2021</th><th>2022</th><th>2023</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="erow">
                <th class="no"></th>
                <th class="month"></th>
                <th class="min"></th>
                <th class="avg"></th>
                <th class="max"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
            <tr class="topRow">
                <th class="no">6</th>
                <th class="month">Juin</th>
                <th class="min">907</th>
                <th class="avg">1098</th>
                <th class="max">1286</th>
                <td>907</td><td>1121</td><td>1286</td><td>1222</td><td>930</td><td>1147</td><td>1165</td><td>1132</td><td>1005</td><td>1062</td><td>1115</td><td>1079</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <th class="no">7</th>
                <th class="month">Juillet</th>
                <th class="min">896</th>
                <th class="avg">1122</th>
                <th class="max">1318</th>
                <td>1088</td><td>1318</td><td>1067</td><td>1166</td><td>1016</td><td>1094</td><td>1201</td><td>1263</td><td>1113</td><td>938</td><td>1302</td><td>896</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <th class="no">8</th>
                <th class="month">Août</th>
                <th class="min">693</th>
                <th class="avg">990</th>
                <th class="max">1175</th>
                <td>1175</td><td>1014</td><td>871</td><td>1033</td><td>1163</td><td>918</td><td>1066</td><td>1026</td><td>1004</td><td>814</td><td>1097</td><td>693</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <th class="no">9</th>
                <th class="month">Septembre</th>
                <th class="min">570</th>
                <th class="avg">778</th>
                <th class="max">911</th>
                <td>816</td><td>836</td><td>570</td><td>851</td><td>911</td><td>761</td><td>779</td><td>807</td><td>735</td><td>825</td><td>803</td><td>648</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <th class="no">10</th>
                <th class="month">Octobre</th>
                <th class="min">284</th>
                <th class="avg">489</th>
                <th class="max">805</th>
                <td>594</td><td>416</td><td>284</td><td>435</td><td>520</td><td>518</td><td>805</td><td>408</td><td>383</td><td>508</td><td>566</td><td>437</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <th class="no">11</th>
                <th class="month">Novembre</th>
                <th class="min">162</th>
                <th class="avg">235</th>
                <th class="max">346</th>
                <td>184</td><td>202</td><td>233</td><td>231</td><td>294</td><td>221</td><td>297</td><td>192</td><td>346</td><td>217</td><td>238</td><td>162</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <th class="no">12</th>
                <th class="month">Décembre</th>
                <th class="min">88</th>
                <th class="avg">171</th>
                <th class="max">286</th>
                <td>129</td><td>237</td><td>96</td><td>222</td><td>286</td><td>88</td><td>155</td><td>223</td><td>124</td><td>164</td><td>195</td><td>135</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <th class="no">1</th>
                <th class="month">Janvier</th>
                <th class="min">94</th>
                <th class="avg">191</th>
                <th class="max">288</th>
                <td>94</td><td>218</td><td>169</td><td>243</td><td>288</td><td>151</td><td>176</td><td>239</td><td>142</td><td>195</td><td>183</td><td/>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <th class="no">2</th>
                <th class="month">Février</th>
                <th class="min">320</th>
                <th class="avg">430</th>
                <th class="max">608</th>
                <td>336</td><td>320</td><td>401</td><td>387</td><td>340</td><td>322</td><td>596</td><td>356</td><td>526</td><td>608</td><td>536</td><td/>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <th class="no">3</th>
                <th class="month">Mars</th>
                <th class="min">561</th>
                <th class="avg">740</th>
                <th class="max">961</th>
                <td>637</td><td>961</td><td>825</td><td>609</td><td>809</td><td>653</td><td>741</td><td>819</td><td>853</td><td>673</td><td>561</td><td/>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <th class="no">4</th>
                <th class="month">Avril</th>
                <th class="min">790</th>
                <th class="avg">980</th>
                <th class="max">1253</th>
                <td>903</td><td>982</td><td>1114</td><td>853</td><td>1078</td><td>889</td><td>921</td><td>1253</td><td>1028</td><td>964</td><td>790</td><td/>
            </tr>
            <tr class="bottomRow">
                <th class="no">5</th>
                <th class="month">Mai</th>
                <th class="min">663</th>
                <th class="avg">1062</th>
                <th class="max">1368</th>
                <td>817</td><td>1074</td><td>1079</td><td>663</td><td>1182</td><td>1203</td><td>1147</td><td>1368</td><td>982</td><td>1139</td><td>1029</td><td/>
            </tr>
          <tr class="erow">
                <th class="no"></th>
                <th class="month"></th>
                <th class="min"></th>
                <th class="avg"></th>
                <th class="max"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
            <tr class="topRow">
                <th class="no">6</th>
                <th class="month">Juin</th>
                <th class="min">907</th>
                <th class="avg">1098</th>
                <th class="max">1286</th>
                <td>907</td><td>1121</td><td>1286</td><td>1222</td><td>930</td><td>1147</td><td>1165</td><td>1132</td><td>1005</td><td>1062</td><td>1115</td><td>1079</td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <th class="no">7</th>
                <th class="month">Juillet</th>
                <th class="min">1946</th>
                <th class="avg">2219</th>
                <th class="max">2439</th>
                <td>1995</td><td>2439</td><td>2353</td><td>2388</td><td>1946</td><td>2241</td><td>2366</td><td>2395</td><td>2118</td><td>2000</td><td>2417</td><td>1975</td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <th class="no">8</th>
                <th class="month">Août</th>
                <th class="min">2668</th>
                <th class="avg">3209</th>
                <th class="max">3514</th>
                <td>3170</td><td>3454</td><td>3224</td><td>3421</td><td>3108</td><td>3159</td><td>3432</td><td>3421</td><td>3122</td><td>2814</td><td>3514</td><td>2668</td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <th class="no">9</th>
                <th class="month">Septembre</th>
                <th class="min">3315</th>
                <th class="avg">3987</th>
                <th class="max">4317</th>
                <td>3986</td><td>4289</td><td>3794</td><td>4272</td><td>4019</td><td>3920</td><td>4211</td><td>4228</td><td>3857</td><td>3639</td><td>4317</td><td>3315</td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <th class="no">10</th>
                <th class="month">Octobre</th>
                <th class="min">3752</th>
                <th class="avg">4477</th>
                <th class="max">5016</th>
                <td>4580</td><td>4705</td><td>4078</td><td>4706</td><td>4539</td><td>4438</td><td>5016</td><td>4636</td><td>4240</td><td>4147</td><td>4883</td><td>3752</td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <th class="no">11</th>
                <th class="month">Novembre</th>
                <th class="min">3915</th>
                <th class="avg">4711</th>
                <th class="max">5313</th>
                <td>4764</td><td>4907</td><td>4311</td><td>4937</td><td>4833</td><td>4659</td><td>5313</td><td>4828</td><td>4586</td><td>4364</td><td>5121</td><td>3915</td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <th class="no">12</th>
                <th class="month">Décembre</th>
                <th class="min">4050</th>
                <th class="avg">4883</th>
                <th class="max">5468</th>
                <td>4893</td><td>5144</td><td>4407</td><td>5159</td><td>5119</td><td>4747</td><td>5468</td><td>5051</td><td>4710</td><td>4528</td><td>5316</td><td>4050</td><td>4050</td><td>4050</td><td>4050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <th class="no">1</th>
                <th class="month">Janvier</th>
                <th class="min">4575</th>
                <th class="avg">5149</th>
                <th class="max">5644</th>
                <td>4987</td><td>5362</td><td>4575</td><td>5401</td><td>5407</td><td>4898</td><td>5644</td><td>5290</td><td>4852</td><td>4723</td><td>5499</td><td/><td>4241</td><td>4144</td><td>4338</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <th class="no">2</th>
                <th class="month">Février</th>
                <th class="min">4976</th>
                <th class="avg">5579</th>
                <th class="max">6240</th>
                <td>5323</td><td>5682</td><td>4976</td><td>5788</td><td>5747</td><td>5220</td><td>6240</td><td>5646</td><td>5378</td><td>5331</td><td>6035</td><td/><td>4670</td><td>4464</td><td>4946</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <th class="no">3</th>
                <th class="month">Mars</th>
                <th class="min">5801</th>
                <th class="avg">6319</th>
                <th class="max">6981</th>
                <td>5960</td><td>6643</td><td>5801</td><td>6397</td><td>6556</td><td>5873</td><td>6981</td><td>6465</td><td>6231</td><td>6004</td><td>6596</td><td/><td>5411</td><td>5025</td><td>5907</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <th class="no">4</th>
                <th class="month">Avril</th>
                <th class="min">6762</th>
                <th class="avg">7298</th>
                <th class="max">7902</th>
                <td>6863</td><td>7625</td><td>6915</td><td>7250</td><td>7634</td><td>6762</td><td>7902</td><td>7718</td><td>7259</td><td>6968</td><td>7386</td><td/><td>6390</td><td>5815</td><td>7160</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="bottomRow">
                <th class="no">5</th>
                <th class="month">Mai</th>
                <th class="min">7680</th>
                <th class="avg">8360</th>
                <th class="max">9086</th>
                <td>7680</td><td>8699</td><td>7994</td><td>7913</td><td>8816</td><td>7965</td><td>9049</td><td>9086</td><td>8241</td><td>8107</td><td>8415</td><td/><td>7452</td><td>6478</td><td>8528</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
  
</html>
```

What must I do to create a fully functional table that scrolls correctly in both directions?

Here is a view (Print Screen of my table on Opera browser) before I begin to scroll horizontally.

[image]

And what I get after scrolling horizontally multiple times (until scroll is impossible):

[image]

As you can see, only first column is visible; all other frozen columns in data rows (green background) have disappeared.

After adding Jun Wen Soh correction, I get following result

[image]

As you can see, first row with titles overwrites 4 first titles and following row's header are not fully readable !

*Without* using JavaScript, what must I do?

Comment: Just for information. I have tested a lot of solution found in Stack Overflow but none are working correctly in both directions with multiple frozen columns. 
If you vote down, can you explain why or give a link to a solution that is working !

Answer (score 0):

For the CSS `left` property, the accepted data types for it's value are [`<length>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) and [`<percentage>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage).

Hence, using an absolute number like `left: 20` does nothing.
Try using the below for a quick fix (not the best way to go about it, as I suspect it might break.)

```
.no {
    left: 0;
}
            
.month {
    left: 20px;
}
            
.min {
    left: 120px;
}
            
.avg {
    left: 160px;
}
            
.max {
    left: 200px;
}
```

Otherwise, i might try to break the table into two. One for the first 5 columns and another for the yearly data from the 6th. column onwards. This way, it might be more adaptable and resilient to changes.

Comment: I have tried but the problem is not resolved. What is displayed is better then before but is not very readable. I added new result in question.

Comment: you can try to increase the value for the left property for the .month selector and subsequently the following ones. This will move the columns more to the right so the text won't be obscured. But one downside of using this approached is, the table might not render the same across all devices due to different 'device pixel ratio' implemented.

Comment: But, in 2024, what is the best approach to implement fixed columns ? With ou without javascript ? Using STICKY properties or OVERFLOW properties ?

Answer (score 0):

After some changes, I obtain following result.

[image]

That is not perfect, but it is the best solution that I found using only `html` and `CSS`.

```css
thead {
    background-color: #FFFFC0;
    color: black;
}
        
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 1.4em;
}

div {
    width: 90vw /* 100% */;
    height: 90vh /* 100% */;
    overflow: scroll;
    outline: 1px solid #777777;
}

table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td  {
    text-align: right;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 4px;
    }

        tr.middleRow td
            {
            border-top: 1px dashed black;
            border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
            border-left: 1px solid black;
            border-right: 1px solid black;
            }

        tr.topRow td
            {
            border-top: 1px solid black;
            border-left: 1px solid black;
            border-right: 1px solid black;
            }

        tr.bottomRow td
            {
            border-bottom: 1px solid black;
            border-left: 1px solid black;
            border-right: 1px solid black;
            }

        tr.erow td 
            {
            height: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            border: 0;
            padding: 2px;
            background-color: white;
            }

th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #FFFFC0;
    color: black;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 4px;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
}

.no {
    width: 20px;
    min-width: 20px;
    }

.month {
    width: 160px;
    min-width: 160px;
    }

.min {
    width: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    }

.avg {
    width: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    }

.max {
    width: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    }

th:nth-child(1) {
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    }

th:nth-child(2) {
    position: sticky;
    left: 32px;
    }

th:nth-child(3) {
    position: sticky;
    left: 200px;
    }

th:nth-child(4) {
    position: sticky;
    left: 308px;
    }

th:nth-child(5) {
    position: sticky;
    left: 416px;
    }

th:nth-child(1),
th:nth-child(2),
th:nth-child(3),
th:nth-child(4),
th:nth-child(5) {
    z-index: 300;
    }

td:nth-child(1) {
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #CCFFCC;;
    }

td:nth-child(2) {
    position: sticky;
    left: 32px;
    background-color: #CCFFCC;;
    }

td:nth-child(3) {
    position: sticky;
    left: 200px;
    background-color: cyan;
    }

td:nth-child(4) {
    position: sticky;
    left: 308px;
    background-color: cyan;
    }

td:nth-child(5) {
    position: sticky;
    left: 416px;
    background-color: cyan;
    }

td:nth-child(1),
td:nth-child(2),
td:nth-child(3),
td:nth-child(4),
td:nth-child(5) {
    z-index: 200;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
        <table>
                <tr>
                    <th class="no">#</th>
                    <th class="month">Mois</th>
                    <th class="min">Min</th>
                    <th class="avg">Avg</th>
                    <th class="max">Max</th>
                    <th>2012</th><th>2013</th><th>2014</th><th>2015</th><th>2016</th><th>2017</th><th>2018</th><th>2019</th><th>2020</th><th>2021</th><th>2022</th><th>2023</th>
                </tr>
              <tr class="erow">
                    <td class="no"></td>
                    <td class="month"></td>
                    <td class="min"></td>
                    <td class="avg"></td>
                    <td class="max"></td>
                    <td colspan="1"></td>
              </tr>
                <tr class="topRow">
                    <td class="no">6</td>
                    <td class="month">Juin</td>
                    <td class="min">907</td>
                    <td class="avg">1098</td>
                    <td class="max">1286</td>
                    <td>907</td><td>1121</td><td>1286</td><td>1222</td><td>930</td><td>1147</td><td>1165</td><td>1132</td><td>1005</td><td>1062</td><td>1115</td><td>1079</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="middleRow">
                    <td class="no">7</td>
                    <td class="month">Juillet</td>
                    <td class="min">896</td>
                    <td class="avg">1122</td>
                    <td class="max">1318</td>
                    <td>1088</td><td>1318</td><td>1067</td><td>1166</td><td>1016</td><td>1094</td><td>1201</td><td>1263</td><td>1113</td><td>938</td><td>1302</td><td>896</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="middleRow">
                    <td class="no">8</td>
                    <td class="month">Août</td>
                    <td class="min">693</td>
                    <td class="avg">990</td>
                    <td class="max">1175</td>
                    <td>1175</td><td>1014</td><td>871</td><td>1033</td><td>1163</td><td>918</td><td>1066</td><td>1026</td><td>1004</td><td>814</td><td>1097</td><td>693</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="middleRow">
                    <td class="no">9</td>
                    <td class="month">Septembre</td>
                    <td class="min">570</td>
                    <td class="avg">778</td>
                    <td class="max">911</td>
                    <td>816</td><td>836</td><td>570</td><td>851</td><td>911</td><td>761</td><td>779</td><td>807</td><td>735</td><td>825</td><td>803</td><td>648</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="middleRow">
                    <td class="no">10</td>
                    <td class="month">Octobre</td>
                    <td class="min">284</td>
                    <td class="avg">489</td>
                    <td class="max">805</td>
                    <td>594</td><td>416</td><td>284</td><td>435</td><td>520</td><td>518</td><td>805</td><td>408</td><td>383</td><td>508</td><td>566</td><td>437</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="middleRow">
                    <td class="no">11</td>
                    <td class="month">Novembre</td>
                    <td class="min">162</td>
                    <td class="avg">235</td>
                    <td class="max">346</td>
                    <td>184</td><td>202</td><td>233</td><td>231</td><td>294</td><td>221</td><td>297</td><td>192</td><td>346</td><td>217</td><td>238</td><td>162</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="middleRow">
                    <td class="no">12</td>
                    <td class="month">Décembre</td>
                    <td class="min">88</td>
                    <td class="avg">171</td>
                    <td class="max">286</td>
                    <td>129</td><td>237</td><td>96</td><td>222</td><td>286</td><td>88</td><td>155</td><td>223</td><td>124</td><td>164</td><td>195</td><td>135</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="middleRow">
                    <td class="no">1</td>
                    <td class="month">Janvier</td>
                    <td class="min">94</td>
                    <td class="avg">191</td>
                    <td class="max">288</td>
                    <td>94</td><td>218</td><td>169</td><td>243</td><td>288</td><td>151</td><td>176</td><td>239</td><td>142</td><td>195</td><td>183</td><td/>
                </tr>
                <tr class="middleRow">
                    <td class="no">2</td>
                    <td class="month">Février</td>
                    <td class="min">320</td>
                    <td class="avg">430</td>
                    <td class="max">608</td>
                    <td>336</td><td>320</td><td>401</td><td>387</td><td>340</td><td>322</td><td>596</td><td>356</td><td>526</td><td>608</td><td>536</td><td/>
                </tr>
                <tr class="middleRow">
                    <td class="no">3</td>
                    <td class="month">Mars</td>
                    <td class="min">561</td>
                    <td class="avg">740</td>
                    <td class="max">961</td>
                    <td>637</td><td>961</td><td>825</td><td>609</td><td>809</td><td>653</td><td>741</td><td>819</td><td>853</td><td>673</td><td>561</td><td/>
                </tr>
                <tr class="middleRow">
                    <td class="no">4</td>
                    <td class="month">Avril</td>
                    <td class="min">790</td>
                    <td class="avg">980</td>
                    <td class="max">1253</td>
                    <td>903</td><td>982</td><td>1114</td><td>853</td><td>1078</td><td>889</td><td>921</td><td>1253</td><td>1028</td><td>964</td><td>790</td><td/>
                </tr>
                <tr class="bottomRow">
                    <td class="no">5</td>
                    <td class="month">Mai</td>
                    <td class="min">663</td>
                    <td class="avg">1062</td>
                    <td class="max">1368</td>
                    <td>817</td><td>1074</td><td>1079</td><td>663</td><td>1182</td><td>1203</td><td>1147</td><td>1368</td><td>982</td><td>1139</td><td>1029</td><td/>
                </tr>
              <tr class="erow">
                    <td class="no"></td>
                    <td class="month"></td>
                    <td class="min"></td>
                    <td class="avg"></td>
                    <td class="max"></td>
                    <td colspan="1"></td>
              </tr>
                <tr class="topRow">
                    <td class="no">6</td>
                    <td class="month">Juin</td>
                    <td class="min">907</td>
                    <td class="avg">1098</td>
                    <td class="max">1286</td>
                    <td>907</td><td>1121</td><td>1286</td><td>1222</td><td>930</td><td>1147</td><td>1165</td><td>1132</td><td>1005</td><td>1062</td><td>1115</td><td>1079</td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="middleRow">
                    <td class="no">7</td>
                    <td class="month">Juillet</td>
                    <td class="min">1946</td>
                    <td class="avg">2219</td>
                    <td class="max">2439</td>
                    <td>1995</td><td>2439</td><td>2353</td><td>2388</td><td>1946</td><td>2241</td><td>2366</td><td>2395</td><td>2118</td><td>2000</td><td>2417</td><td>1975</td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="middleRow">
                    <td class="no">8</td>
                    <td class="month">Août</td>
                    <td class="min">2668</td>
                    <td class="avg">3209</td>
                    <td class="max">3514</td>
                    <td>3170</td><td>3454</td><td>3224</td><td>3421</td><td>3108</td><td>3159</td><td>3432</td><td>3421</td><td>3122</td><td>2814</td><td>3514</td><td>2668</td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="middleRow">
                    <td class="no">9</td>
                    <td class="month">Septembre</td>
                    <td class="min">3315</td>
                    <td class="avg">3987</td>
                    <td class="max">4317</td>
                    <td>3986</td><td>4289</td><td>3794</td><td>4272</td><td>4019</td><td>3920</td><td>4211</td><td>4228</td><td>3857</td><td>3639</td><td>4317</td><td>3315</td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="middleRow">
                    <td class="no">10</td>
                    <td class="month">Octobre</td>
                    <td class="min">3752</td>
                    <td class="avg">4477</td>
                    <td class="max">5016</td>
                    <td>4580</td><td>4705</td><td>4078</td><td>4706</td><td>4539</td><td>4438</td><td>5016</td><td>4636</td><td>4240</td><td>4147</td><td>4883</td><td>3752</td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="middleRow">
                    <td class="no">11</td>
                    <td class="month">Novembre</td>
                    <td class="min">3915</td>
                    <td class="avg">4711</td>
                    <td class="max">5313</td>
                    <td>4764</td><td>4907</td><td>4311</td><td>4937</td><td>4833</td><td>4659</td><td>5313</td><td>4828</td><td>4586</td><td>4364</td><td>5121</td><td>3915</td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="middleRow">
                    <td class="no">12</td>
                    <td class="month">Décembre</td>
                    <td class="min">4050</td>
                    <td class="avg">4883</td>
                    <td class="max">5468</td>
                    <td>4893</td><td>5144</td><td>4407</td><td>5159</td><td>5119</td><td>4747</td><td>5468</td><td>5051</td><td>4710</td><td>4528</td><td>5316</td><td>4050</td><td>4050</td><td>4050</td><td>4050</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="middleRow">
                    <td class="no">1</td>
                    <td class="month">Janvier</td>
                    <td class="min">4575</td>
                    <td class="avg">5149</td>
                    <td class="max">5644</td>
                    <td>4987</td><td>5362</td><td>4575</td><td>5401</td><td>5407</td><td>4898</td><td>5644</td><td>5290</td><td>4852</td><td>4723</td><td>5499</td><td/><td>4241</td><td>4144</td><td>4338</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="middleRow">
                    <td class="no">2</td>
                    <td class="month">Février</td>
                    <td class="min">4976</td>
                    <td class="avg">5579</td>
                    <td class="max">6240</td>
                    <td>5323</td><td>5682</td><td>4976</td><td>5788</td><td>5747</td><td>5220</td><td>6240</td><td>5646</td><td>5378</td><td>5331</td><td>6035</td><td/><td>4670</td><td>4464</td><td>4946</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="middleRow">
                    <td class="no">3</td>
                    <td class="month">Mars</td>
                    <td class="min">5801</td>
                    <td class="avg">6319</td>
                    <td class="max">6981</td>
                    <td>5960</td><td>6643</td><td>5801</td><td>6397</td><td>6556</td><td>5873</td><td>6981</td><td>6465</td><td>6231</td><td>6004</td><td>6596</td><td/><td>5411</td><td>5025</td><td>5907</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="middleRow">
                    <td class="no">4</td>
                    <td class="month">Avril</td>
                    <td class="min">6762</td>
                    <td class="avg">7298</td>
                    <td class="max">7902</td>
                    <td>6863</td><td>7625</td><td>6915</td><td>7250</td><td>7634</td><td>6762</td><td>7902</td><td>7718</td><td>7259</td><td>6968</td><td>7386</td><td/><td>6390</td><td>5815</td><td>7160</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="bottomRow">
                    <td class="no">5</td>
                    <td class="month">Mai</td>
                    <td class="min">7680</td>
                    <td class="avg">8360</td>
                    <td class="max">9086</td>
                    <td>7680</td><td>8699</td><td>7994</td><td>7913</td><td>8816</td><td>7965</td><td>9049</td><td>9086</td><td>8241</td><td>8107</td><td>8415</td><td/><td>7452</td><td>6478</td><td>8528</td>
                </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I continued to search a solution because `STICKY` solution is not perfect.

Now, I have splitted my original table in 2 tables; one LEFT with fixed columns and one RIGHT with variable columns.

I use some Javascript to synchronize vertical scrolling on both tables.

For both tables, I have splitted them in 2 tables, one for headers and a second for table's values.

I have also made some minor improvement to scroll table horizontally year by year.

Here is my code ...

```js
const varbloc = document.querySelector("#varbloc");
const fixbloc = document.querySelector("#fixbloc");
const varheaderdiv = document.querySelector("#varheaderdiv");
const varheader = document.querySelector("#varheader");
const iColWidth = varheader.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].offsetWidth;

var iLastScrollLeft = 0;

varbloc.addEventListener("scrollend", (event) => {
    //varheaderdiv.scrollLeft = varbloc.scrollLeft;
    if (varbloc.scrollLeft < iLastScrollLeft)
        {
        var iNewScrollLeft = (Math.floor(Math.round(varbloc.scrollLeft / iColWidth)) - 1) * iColWidth;
        varheaderdiv.scrollLeft = iNewScrollLeft;
        varbloc.scrollLeft = iNewScrollLeft;
        iLastScrollLeft = iNewScrollLeft;
        }
    else
    if (varbloc.scrollLeft > iLastScrollLeft)
        {
        var iNewScrollLeft = (Math.floor(Math.round(varbloc.scrollLeft / iColWidth)) + 1) * iColWidth;
        varheaderdiv.scrollLeft = iNewScrollLeft;
        varbloc.scrollLeft = iNewScrollLeft;
        iLastScrollLeft = iNewScrollLeft;
        }
});

varbloc.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
    fixbloc.scrollTop = varbloc.scrollTop;
});
```

```css
body
    {
    min-height: 100%;
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 1.4em;
    }

table
    {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }

.fixline
    {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
    }

.varline
    {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
    }

.main 
    {
    overflow: hidden;
    }

.left
    {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    }

.right
    {
    width: calc(100% - 480px - 10px);
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(480px + 10px);
    top: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    }

#fixbloc
    {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    }

#varbloc
    {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    }

#fixheaderdiv
    {
    height: 50px;
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    }

#varheaderdiv
    {
    height: 50px;
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    }

td
    {
    text-align: right;
    width: 80px;
    min-width: 80px;
    padding: 4px;
    }

tr.middleRow td
    {
    border-top: 1px dashed black;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    }

tr.topRow td
    {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    }

tr.bottomRow td
    {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    }

.fixheader td
    {
    background-color: lightyellow;
    color: black;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-weight: normal;
    }

.tdempty
    {
    border: 0px !important;
    background-color: white !important;
    }

.tdend
    {
    border: 0px !important;
    background-color: white !important;
    width: 2000px !important;
    min-width: 2000px !important;
    }

#varheader td
    {
    background-color: lightyellow;
    color: black;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-weight: normal;
    }

.fixvalue td,
.fixcumul td
    {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    color: black;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 4px;
    font-weight: normal;
    }

.no {
    width: 40px !important;
    min-width: 40px !important;
    }

.month
    {
    width: 150px;
    }

.min
    {
    width: 80px;
    }

.avg
    {
    width: 80px;
    }

.max
    {
    width: 80px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="left">
        <div id="fixheaderdiv">  
        <table class="fixheader">
            <tr>
                <td class="no">#</td>
                <td class="month">Mois</td>
                <td class="min">Min</td>
                <td class="avg">Avg</td>
                <td class="max">Max</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div id="fixbloc">  
        <table class="fixvalue">
            <tr class="topRow">
                <td class="no">6</td>
                <td class="month">Juin</td>
                <td class="min">300</td>
                <td class="avg">471</td>
                <td class="max">665</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <td class="no">7</td>
                <td class="month">Juillet</td>
                <td class="min">314</td>
                <td class="avg">481</td>
                <td class="max">743</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <td class="no">8</td>
                <td class="month">Août</td>
                <td class="min">272</td>
                <td class="avg">463</td>
                <td class="max">723</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <td class="no">9</td>
                <td class="month">Septembre</td>
                <td class="min">336</td>
                <td class="avg">538</td>
                <td class="max">750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <td class="no">10</td>
                <td class="month">Octobre</td>
                <td class="min">423</td>
                <td class="avg">696</td>
                <td class="max">969</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <td class="no">11</td>
                <td class="month">Novembre</td>
                <td class="min">590</td>
                <td class="avg">976</td>
                <td class="max">1798</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <td class="no">12</td>
                <td class="month">Décembre</td>
                <td class="min">812</td>
                <td class="avg">1248</td>
                <td class="max">2008</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <td class="no">1</td>
                <td class="month">Janvier</td>
                <td class="min">784</td>
                <td class="avg">1513</td>
                <td class="max">2349</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <td class="no">2</td>
                <td class="month">Février</td>
                <td class="min">704</td>
                <td class="avg">1201</td>
                <td class="max">1774</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <td class="no">3</td>
                <td class="month">Mars</td>
                <td class="min">667</td>
                <td class="avg">1159</td>
                <td class="max">1796</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <td class="no">4</td>
                <td class="month">Avril</td>
                <td class="min">585</td>
                <td class="avg">857</td>
                <td class="max">1202</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="bottomRow">
                <td class="no">5</td>
                <td class="month">Mai</td>
                <td class="min">301</td>
                <td class="avg">596</td>
                <td class="max">873</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="fixline">&nbsp;</div>
            <table class="fixcumul">
            <tr class="topRow">
                <td class="no">6</td>
                <td class="month">Juin</td>
                <td class="min">300</td>
                <td class="avg">471</td>
                <td class="max">665</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <td class="no">7</td>
                <td class="month">Juillet</td>
                <td class="min">653</td>
                <td class="avg">952</td>
                <td class="max">1274</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <td class="no">8</td>
                <td class="month">Août</td>
                <td class="min">925</td>
                <td class="avg">1415</td>
                <td class="max">1880</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <td class="no">9</td>
                <td class="month">Septembre</td>
                <td class="min">1308</td>
                <td class="avg">1953</td>
                <td class="max">2559</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <td class="no">10</td>
                <td class="month">Octobre</td>
                <td class="min">1829</td>
                <td class="avg">2649</td>
                <td class="max">3300</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <td class="no">11</td>
                <td class="month">Novembre</td>
                <td class="min">2584</td>
                <td class="avg">3625</td>
                <td class="max">4928</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <td class="no">12</td>
                <td class="month">Décembre</td>
                <td class="min">3968</td>
                <td class="avg">4851</td>
                <td class="max">6915</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <td class="no">1</td>
                <td class="month">Janvier</td>
                <td class="min">4943</td>
                <td class="avg">6364</td>
                <td class="max">8822</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <td class="no">2</td>
                <td class="month">Février</td>
                <td class="min">5731</td>
                <td class="avg">7565</td>
                <td class="max">10223</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <td class="no">3</td>
                <td class="month">Mars</td>
                <td class="min">6398</td>
                <td class="avg">8724</td>
                <td class="max">11717</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                <td class="no">4</td>
                <td class="month">Avril</td>
                <td class="min">7424</td>
                <td class="avg">9581</td>
                <td class="max">12490</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="bottomRow">
                <td class="no">5</td>
                <td class="month">Mai</td>
                <td class="min">7725</td>
                <td class="avg">10178</td>
                <td class="max">13116</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="fixline">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div id="varheaderdiv">  
        <table id="varheader">
            <tr>
                <td>2012</td><td>2013</td><td>2014</td><td>2015</td><td>2016</td><td>2017</td><td>2018</td><td>2019</td><td>2020</td><td>2021</td><td>2022</td><td>2023</td>
                <td>Min</td>
                <td>Avg</td>
                <td>Max</td>
                <td class="tdend">&nbsp</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div> 
        <div id="varbloc">  
        <table class="varvalue">
            <tr class="topRow">
                 <td>520</td><td>570</td><td>492</td><td>438</td><td>527</td><td>665</td><td>441</td><td>531</td><td>431</td><td>411</td><td>327</td><td>300</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdend">&nbsp</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                 <td>498</td><td>508</td><td>518</td><td>535</td><td>630</td><td>581</td><td>314</td><td>743</td><td>413</td><td>339</td><td>326</td><td>360</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdend">&nbsp</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                 <td>519</td><td>478</td><td>467</td><td>593</td><td>723</td><td>563</td><td>466</td><td>425</td><td>401</td><td>289</td><td>272</td><td>367</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdend">&nbsp</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                 <td>632</td><td>561</td><td>592</td><td>556</td><td>546</td><td>750</td><td>609</td><td>553</td><td>565</td><td>336</td><td>383</td><td>370</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdend">&nbsp</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                 <td>423</td><td>588</td><td>614</td><td>699</td><td>846</td><td>741</td><td>630</td><td>878</td><td>655</td><td>794</td><td>521</td><td>969</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdend">&nbsp</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                 <td>636</td><td>885</td><td>590</td><td>669</td><td>813</td><td>781</td><td>875</td><td>1798</td><td>1349</td><td>1055</td><td>755</td><td>1503</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdend">&nbsp</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                 <td>1066</td><td>834</td><td>812</td><td>892</td><td>1025</td><td>1010</td><td>1559</td><td>1987</td><td>2008</td><td>1150</td><td>1384</td><td/>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdend">&nbsp</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                 <td>1113</td><td>784</td><td>858</td><td>1203</td><td>1080</td><td>1447</td><td>2349</td><td>1907</td><td>1978</td><td>1815</td><td>2106</td><td/>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdend">&nbsp</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                 <td>976</td><td>770</td><td>788</td><td>826</td><td>704</td><td>1737</td><td>1689</td><td>1401</td><td>1358</td><td>1189</td><td>1774</td><td/>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdend">&nbsp</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                 <td>852</td><td>912</td><td>667</td><td>884</td><td>833</td><td>1796</td><td>1458</td><td>1494</td><td>1371</td><td>1317</td><td>1170</td><td/>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdend">&nbsp</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                 <td>723</td><td>585</td><td>1026</td><td>735</td><td>816</td><td>878</td><td>901</td><td>773</td><td>1202</td><td>841</td><td>949</td><td/>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdend">&nbsp</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="bottomRow">
                 <td>682</td><td>524</td><td>301</td><td>525</td><td>637</td><td>549</td><td>740</td><td>626</td><td>873</td><td>348</td><td>755</td><td/>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdempty">&nbsp</td>
                <td class="tdend">&nbsp</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="varline2" class="varline">&nbsp;</div>
        <table class="varcumul">
            <tr class="topRow">
                 <td>520</td><td>570</td><td>492</td><td>438</td><td>527</td><td>665</td><td>441</td><td>531</td><td>431</td><td>411</td><td>327</td><td>300</td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                 <td>1018</td><td>1078</td><td>1011</td><td>973</td><td>1157</td><td>1246</td><td>755</td><td>1274</td><td>844</td><td>750</td><td>653</td><td>660</td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                 <td>1538</td><td>1556</td><td>1478</td><td>1566</td><td>1880</td><td>1809</td><td>1221</td><td>1699</td><td>1245</td><td>1039</td><td>925</td><td>1027</td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                 <td>2169</td><td>2117</td><td>2070</td><td>2122</td><td>2426</td><td>2559</td><td>1830</td><td>2252</td><td>1810</td><td>1375</td><td>1308</td><td>1397</td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                 <td>2592</td><td>2705</td><td>2684</td><td>2821</td><td>3272</td><td>3300</td><td>2460</td><td>3130</td><td>2465</td><td>2169</td><td>1829</td><td>2365</td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                 <td>3228</td><td>3590</td><td>3274</td><td>3489</td><td>4085</td><td>4081</td><td>3335</td><td>4928</td><td>3814</td><td>3224</td><td>2584</td><td>3869</td><td>3869</td><td>3869</td><td>3869</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                 <td>4294</td><td>4424</td><td>4086</td><td>4382</td><td>5110</td><td>5091</td><td>4894</td><td>6915</td><td>5822</td><td>4375</td><td>3968</td><td/><td>5117</td><td>4681</td><td>5877</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                 <td>5407</td><td>5208</td><td>4943</td><td>5584</td><td>6190</td><td>6538</td><td>7242</td><td>8822</td><td>7800</td><td>6190</td><td>6074</td><td/><td>6630</td><td>5465</td><td>8226</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                 <td>6383</td><td>5978</td><td>5731</td><td>6410</td><td>6894</td><td>8275</td><td>8931</td><td>10223</td><td>9158</td><td>7379</td><td>7848</td><td/><td>7831</td><td>6168</td><td>10000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                 <td>7235</td><td>6890</td><td>6398</td><td>7294</td><td>7727</td><td>10071</td><td>10389</td><td>11717</td><td>10529</td><td>8696</td><td>9018</td><td/><td>8990</td><td>6835</td><td>11796</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="middleRow">
                 <td>7958</td><td>7475</td><td>7424</td><td>8029</td><td>8543</td><td>10949</td><td>11290</td><td>12490</td><td>11731</td><td>9537</td><td>9967</td><td/><td>9847</td><td>7420</td><td>12998</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="bottomRow">
                 <td>8640</td><td>7999</td><td>7725</td><td>8554</td><td>9180</td><td>11498</td><td>12030</td><td>13116</td><td>12604</td><td>9885</td><td>10722</td><td/><td>10444</td><td>7721</td><td>13871</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```